Typescript not getting installed using npm
I was starting a tutorial on Typescript.
Did this to install it globally using npm
npm i typescript -g

But, it gets stuck on the first line itself while installing and shows this -
(⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂) ⠦ idealTree:lib: sill idealTree buildDeps

Please tell how to resolve this?
I tried to look online but didn't find anything significant.

nvm, I found the solution. :)

Update npm:
npm install -g npm@latest
Clear npm cache:
npm cache clean --force
Run npm install with verbose output:
npm install typescript -g --verbose
